# Creating release build for dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, release-builds

I am developing a dynamic framework using Xcode 6.4. I am able to generate the debug build for it which is available in the `Debug-iphoneos` and `Debug-iphonesimulator` folders under the `Products` group. However, I am not able to generate the release build for the same framework. I tried editing the scheme but it didn't work.

Also, I don't want to go with the archive option as it works only for non-Simulator devices. I want the release build to work for both Simulators and non-Simulator devices. So, I want the release build to be generated in the `Release-iphoneos` and `Release-iphonesimulator` folders similar to how it is for debug builds.

What is the procedure for generating a release build of a framework?

As shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBdB7.png) screenshot, my `Release-iphoneos` and `Release-iphonesimulator` folders remain empty. I want my builds to be output there.

Comment: are you sure, framework or library?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through this post: https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c

It's quite an involved process of building a release framework for Device and Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but It's about how to create universal build. Universal build I am able to generate using debug builds for simulator and device. I want the similar release builds for device and simulator, not the universal build. there should be 2 separate release builds. One for device and other for simulator

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a release build of your framework for both `iphonesimulator` and `iphoneos` devices with the following `xcodebuild` commands:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <name of workspace>.xcworkspace -scheme <name of scheme> -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos

xcodebuild -workspace <name of workspace>.xcworkspace -scheme <name of scheme> -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator
```

You can change the value of the `-configuration` argument from `Release` to `Debug` in order to produce a debug build.

Note that you may need to provide the `-project` argument instead of `-workspace` if your target is part of an Xcode project only and not part of an Xcode workspace. Run the `xcodebuild -help` command for the full list of `xcodebuild` options.

If you want to join up your `iphoneos` and `iphonesimulator` builds into a single binary, you can do that with the `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` command as follows:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "Release-iphoneos/<name of framework>.framework" \
    -framework "Release-iphonesimulator/<name of framework>.framework" \
    -output "<name of framework>.xcframework"
```

Note that you may need to set your framework target's `Build Libraries for Distribution` Build Setting to `YES` in order to build it as an XCFramework. See [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev544efab96) for the official guide to creating an XCFramework.